# JavaScript: Add pixel position to href of each link

Tags: javascript

is it possible to add the coordinates of a href-link into the target-query?

I mean something like this:

```
<a href="index.php?action=create&id=123&x=[...]&y=[...]" id="123">Link 123</a>
```

This should add the coordinates of the link (id) on the page into the query via document.write() or something.

PS: Should work without JQuery and with IE11 :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a bare `href` attach an event using javascript, grab the X & Y you want (maybe screen or client as demonstrated below) and redirect the `location.href` to your chosen page building up the url as needed (commented out below so you can see output).

```js
document.querySelector('#link').addEventListener("click",evt => {
  console.log("screen",evt.screenX,evt.screenY);
  console.log("client",evt.clientX,evt.clientY);
  //location.href = "somepage.php?x=" + evt.screenX + "&y=" + evt.screenY
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
```

By setting the value of `location.href` in the event handler the behaviour for the user will be the same as having clicked a link with an `href` attribute.

Comment: If the link doesn't go anywhere, may I suggest a `button` be used instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think the intention is that it does go somewhere as per the question and the commented out line for illustration.